# Jsoup - How to query this?

Tags: android, jsoup

this is probably fairly easy in Jsoup, but I haven't found anything about that in jsoup cookbook so I am asking here.

```
<div class="team" style="float: right; background: url('http://teampage.com')"></div>
```

How to get content of url using Jsoup?

Comment: This is CSS (Style attribute is CSS) , and jSoup cannot parse css.  You have to get the contents of the style attribute, and extract the URL using a regular expression. Will see if I have time to post an answer.

Comment: Well, I was expecting that I will have to use regex to that one. Just thought there is a roundabout. Anyway, thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

(Pulled out of [one of my projects](https://github.com/JonasCz/save-for-offline/blob/master/app/src/main/java/jonas/tool/saveForOffline/SaveService.java), so you will have to adapt it)

```
public void getURLsFromCSS(String cssToParse) {
    //cssToParse -- The css string to get URL's from

    String patternString = "url(\\s*\\(\\s*['\"]*\\s*)(.*?)\\s*['\"]*\\s*\\)"; //I hate regexes...
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(cssToParse);

    //find everything inside url(" ... ")
    while (matcher.find()) {

        System.out.println("URL:" + matcher.group().replaceAll(patternString, "$2"));

    }
}
```

You have to get the contents of the style attribute from jSoup, and give it to this method. If url's are relative to the HTML document, You may need to make them absolute, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks. I really hate regex so you have made my life easier :)

Comment: Glad I could help :-) I hate regex too, btw.